# How to switch Nebular Calendar language without refresh browser?

Tags: angular, calendar, internationalization, nebular

I using Nebular Calendar [**NbRangepickerComponent**] as below

[image: Calendar in english]

when I switch i18n button, I need to refresh the whole page  for selected language

[image]

**app.modele**

```
import { LocaleService } from '@core/services/locale.service';
import localeEN from '@angular/common/locales/en';
import localeZhHant from '@angular/common/locales/zh-Hant';
registerLocaleData(localeEN, 'en');
registerLocaleData(localeZhHant, 'zh-Hant');

providers: [
    {
        provide: LOCALE_ID,
        deps: [LocaleService],
        useFactory: (localeService) => localeService.getLocale(),
    },
],
```

**locale.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})

export class LocaleService {
constructor() {}

localeStr: string;

setLocale(value: string) {
    this.localeStr = value;
}

getLocale(): string {
    this.localeStr = localStorage.getItem('lang') === 'zh-TW' ? 'zh-Hant' : 'en';
    return this.localeStr;
}

public registerLang(lang: string) {
    if (!lang) return;
    switch (lang) {
        case 'en-US': {
            this.localeStr = 'en';
            break;
        }
        case 'zh-TW': {
            this.localeStr = 'zh-Hant';
            break;
        }
        default: {
            this.localeStr = 'zh-Hant';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**i18n button**

```
getLang(data) {
    this.languageMenu = [
        { title: data.TW, tag: 'zh-TW' },
        { title: data.US, tag: 'en-US' },
    ];

    this.localeService.registerLang('en-US');
}
```

**NbRangepickerComponent**

```
<nb-rangepicker #formpicker [min]="min" [max]="max" (rangeChange)="rangeChange($event)"></nb-rangepicker>
```

**[Question] How to switch language without refresh browser?**

Comment: use ngx-translate, this library fix this problem automatically.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur answer, could you give me a demo? actually, I have using ngx-translate already, but it dosen't fix this problem.

Comment: I found this [example](https://stackblitz.com/github/ngx-translate/example) on ngx-translate github, so go ahead step by step with that ripo.

Comment: I already import ngx-translate module in my project, it work well with angular i18n, but not working with Nebular Component NbCalendarComponent, this component seem to using angular LOCALE_ID token for localization, but it need to refresh the whole page to change language.

[NbCalendarComponent](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/datepicker/overview#nbdatepickerdirective)